# Google Analytics not tracking clicks

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, click-tracking, google-tag-manager

I am using Google Analytics with the Google Tag Manager. I have set up triggers for all the links I want to track and have tested it in preview.  They all work fine.  So I go into the Analytics report page and go to Realtime -> Events. When I click the links it shows up on the realtime bar graph.  However, I can't find anywhere to actually see what links were clicked.  There are seperate triggers for each link in tag manager. I thought it would be under Behavior -> Events but that says 0 events triggered, ever. Am I looking in the wrong spot or is there something else that needs set up?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? For example, if you click a link with href="/some/page/somelink.html", are you expecting to see "/some/page/somelink.html" in your reports? Unless you have configured the event to reflect which actual link was clicked (for example, in the label), you won't be able to find that info through events.

Comment: Have you added the click listener tag and fired it on the all the pages you want to track events?

Answer (score 1):

When you are tracking events, they will not show up in standard reports for about 24 hours (usually less) even though you can see them right away in Real-Time. You mentioned that "they all work fine", so I am assuming that you have all your listeners in place. If you want to see exactly which links were clicked, then you would have to have included that in your event parameters that you are sending in, eg:

- category = button
- action = click
- label = footer

You can include any information about your link in the event parameters, like {{element url}}, {{element id}}, {{element text}}, so that should help you pinpoint which element fired your event.

You are looking in the correct part of the reports, Behaviour > Events, but just need to wait for the events to show up, as I mentioned.